# Refresh view after DB insert React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am creating an app with React/Redux, I have successfully managed to create an action/reducer to insert a record into my database - which is [ForerunnerDB](http://www.forerunnerdb.com/)

My code so far looks like this:

PAGE

```
class Projects extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.FetchProjects();
  }

  renderProjects() {
    return this.props.projects.map( ( project ) => {
      return (
        <li key={ project._id } >
          <Link to={ `/pages/${project._id}` } >{ project.title } { project.timestamp.toString() }</Link>
        </li>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="projects container">
        <div className="projects">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <CreateNewProject />
            </li>
            { this.renderProjects() }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps( state ) {
  return {
    projects: state.projects.all
  }
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps, actions )( Projects );
```

I am using the `<CreateNewProject />` component to insert the record and the `renderProjects()` method to fetch the list of projects. The projects are rendered just fine if I refresh the page, but I cannot figure out to get the list to update at the point a record is inserted into the DB automatically.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT

PROJECTS actions

```
// Fetch existing projects
export function FetchProjects() {
  return ( dispatch ) => {
    // Load projects collection
    projectsCollection.load( ( err ) => {
      // if there are no errors
      if( !err ) {
        // Set up action payload
        const projects = projectsCollection.find();
        // Dispatch the action using the above
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_PROJECTS,
          payload: projects
        });
      // If there's an error loading the projects collection
      } else {
        //Log the error
        console.log( `ERR! ${err}` );
      }
    });
  }
}
// Create new project
export function CreateProject( { projectName } ) {
  return ( dispatch ) => {
    // Load projects collection
    projectsCollection.load( ( err ) => {
      // If there are no errors
      if( !err ) {
        // Set up action payload
        // Insert record into projects collection
        const projectCreate = projectsCollection.insert({
          title: projectName,
          timestamp: fdb.make( new Date() )
        }, ( result ) => {
          // If insertion is successful
          if( result.inserted.length ) {
            // Save the projects collection (persisted to local storage)
            projectsCollection.save( ( err ) => {
              // If there are no errors
              if( !err ) {
                console.log( result.inserted[0] )
              } else {
                // Log the error
                console.log( `ERR! ${err}` );
              }
            });
          } else {
            // Log the failed insertion
            console.log( `ERR! ${result.failed}` );
          }
        });
        // Dispatch the action using the above
        dispatch({
          type: CREATE_PROJECT,
          payload: projectCreate
        });
      // If there's an error loading the projects collection
      } else {
        // Log the error
        console.log( `ERR! ${err}` );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

FETCH_PROJECTS reducer

```
// Import dependencies
import { FETCH_PROJECTS } from '../../actions/types';

// Set inital state
const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [] }

export default function( state = INITIAL_STATE, action ) {
  switch( action.type ) {
    case FETCH_PROJECTS:
      return { ...state, all: action.payload }
  }

  return state;
}
```

CREATE_PROJECTS reducer

```
import { CREATE_PROJECT } from '../../actions/types';

export default function( state = {}, action ) {
  switch( action.type ) {
    case CREATE_PROJECT:
      return { ...state, projects: action.payload }
  }

  return state;
}
```

Comment: looks like you should use one more time `this.props.FetchProjects()` to get data up to date. That's occurs because you are using `props` which dont trigger `render` method, instead of `state`

Comment: @TheReason where would I put that call is there an appropriate lifecycle method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an action to CreateNewProject component.  That way you can fire the action to insert a new record from the component.  That action will then update the store via a reducer.  Once the store is updated, it will trigger an update to the Projects component since it maps one of its props to the projects store.

EDIT -- additional code provided in question reveals more:

I noticed something which may be causing the issue.  Inside PROJECTS actions, the function CreateProject has an issue with synchronicity.  You attempted to create `projectCreate` and then pass that as the payload in your action.  The problem is that `projectsCollection.insert()` is an asynchronous function (indicated by the callback).  What this means is the `dispatch()` call has an undefined value for `projectCreate`.

I suggest putting the `dispatch()` call inside the last callback, `projectsCollection.save()`:

```
      projectsCollection.save( ( err ) => {
          // If there are no errors
          if( !err ) {
            console.log( result.inserted[0] )
            // dispatch the successful result
            dispatch({
              type: CREATE_PROJECT,
              payload: result.inserted[0]
            });
          } 
          ...
       }
```

Comment: thats exactly what I have done. I will edit my question above to show the actions/reducers

Comment: thats make sense. I have tried what you suggest but unfortunately I haven't managed to get it working. Am I referring to state correctly in the reducers? Might be a daft suggestion but this is my first project using React Redux.

Comment: I've never used the approach you're using, so I cannot comment if its good or bad.  I use ImmutableJS for my reducers to ensure they are pure.  Typically I have only one reducer per store, and I handle all the actions supported by that reducer in a switch statement.  I would suggest using Object.assign() to merge new data with the current state; as that will return a new object.  Perhaps it would be beneficial for you to read http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html